# Aspose - convert HTML string to PDF byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, aspose

In an ASP.NET MVC 4.8 C# app, I have an HTML string in memory that needs to be converted to a PDF byte array using Aspose's library. All the processing occurs in-memory and nothing is saved to disk. The HTML is generated on the fly and PDF isn't saved to disk but will be attached to an email and sent.

The [Aspose docs](https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/convert-html-to-pdf/) explain how to load an HTML from disk and save a PDF to disk. I can't find anything on how to do this all in-memory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer with the relevant code:

```
byte[] pdfBytes = null;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdfDocument = new Document();
    var htmlFragment = new HtmlFragment(myHtmlString);
    pdfDocument.Pages.Add().Paragraphs.Add(htmlFragment);
    pdfDocument.Save(ms);
    pdfDocument.Dispose();
    pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```